# $\frac{x^2 -4}{x-4} \rightarrow -5$ as $x \rightarrow 3$, proving the limit from first principles. ($\delta - \epsilon$).

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

This is a follow up to a previous post. I am sorry of this is considered spamming but I have made significant progress of the question since then. Hopefully I'm on the right track, an tips or advice on my methods would be much appreciated!

I have been asked to prove the limit of $\frac{x^2 -4}{x-4} \rightarrow -5$ as $x \rightarrow 3$. First I fix $\epsilon >0$ and find $\delta>0$ such that.

$$0<|x-3| <\delta \implies \bigg|\frac{x^2 -4}{x-4} + 5\bigg| < \epsilon$$

$$\impliedby \bigg|\frac{x^2+5x -24}{x-4}\bigg| < \epsilon$$

$$\impliedby \bigg|\frac{(x+8)(x-3)}{x-4}\bigg| < \epsilon$$

$$\impliedby \bigg|(x-3)\frac{x+8}{x-4}\bigg| < \epsilon$$

If $|x-3| \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then $[2\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{2}]$. Then $\frac{x+8}{x+4} \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $\frac{|x-3|}{2} < \epsilon \iff |x-3|<2\epsilon $.

Thus any $\delta \leq$ min$(\frac{1}{2}, 2\epsilon)$ has the required property.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You need to bound $\dfrac{|x+8|}{|x-4|}$ from above and not from below. A suitable bound is $24$. Note that we don't need the tightest bound possible but just some bound. Then $\delta =\min(1/2,\epsilon /24)$ works.

Comment: Please, edit your previous post with the relevant new information instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice for $\delta$ does not work.

Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$.

Then your formula gives $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$.

If $x = 3.4$ then

$$\quad \bigg|(x-3) \; \frac{x+8}{x-4}\bigg| = 7.6$$

---

If $x \in [2\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{2}]$ then

$$\quad |x+8| \le 12 $$

If $x \in [2\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{2}]$ then

$$\quad |x-4| \ge \frac{1}{2} $$

It follows that for every $x \in [2\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{2}]$ that

$$\quad \bigg|\frac{x+8}{x-4}\bigg| = \frac{|x+8|}{|x-4|} \le 24$$

To solve the OP's problem, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ challenge let

$$ \delta = \text{min}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon}{24}\bigg)$$

Comment: There is no need to find maximum, any upper bound will do. For numerator we see it less than 12 and denominator greater than $1/2$ so that $24$ works as a nice bound.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Made the changes. Yea, you can use wolfram but it is much better for all steps to be completely nailed down in as simple a way as possible.

Comment: My +1 was already there.